# Finding instance variables for each object

Tags: java, oop, this, instance-variables

I have to do an assignment where I pass over objects as parameters to the parent class. If I call the following:

```
candy1.eat(candy2);
```

Both have the same instance variables (yummy & delicious), I know that If I have to do some calculation using the 2 objects in the same method, the instance variables for candy1 will be:

```
this.yummy;
this.delicous;
```

However, how would I go about finding the instance variables for candy2?

Comment: Have you tried reflection?

Comment: do you mean `candy2.GetYummy()`? You need Getters and Setters for this. `public string GetYummy { return yummy; }` and `public void setYummy(string yum){ yummy = yum; }`

Comment: It is my understanding that you have direct access to this fields within candy1 if candy1 and candy2 are of the same type.

Comment: No eat is a method in my parent class that performs an operations on both objects in the same method. I have to work with the values of both candy1 and candy2. If i worked with the values of the candy1 object, then the variables work as I stated as above. However, since I passed the candy2 object as a parameter, I have no clue what the syntax is to access the values of the yummy and delicious variables for candy2. The "this" notation worked with candy1, but of course it won't work for candy2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just found out how to do it, so I will post an example below

```
public Snack eat(Snack pieceOfCandy){
    //variables for the candy1 object
    this.yummy = "Very yummy";
    this.delicious = "Very delicous";

    //variables for candy2 object
    pieceofCandy.yummy = "not that great";
    pieceOfCandy.delicious = "not delicious";
}
```

Sorta like that. If I'm working in the method then that's what it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that If I have to do some calculation using the 2 objects in the same method, the instance variables for candy1 will be:

```
this.yummy;
this.delicous;
```

Wrong. They are

```
candy.yummy;
candy.delicious;
```

... assuming the variable name is 'candy'. That answers your question completely.